# Hibernate self-reference mapping puzzle

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, bidirectional

I am trying to map a class

```
Class Node {
Node parent;
List<Node> children;
}
```

I have tried various combinations of many-to-one and one-to-many but nothing seems to work. I would have pasted my mapping file, but I have tried so many things that I have no idea which one to paste. Please help me :( Also I have been successful in mapping the class if I was using SET instead of LIST, but when I use list, i am not able to update the column used to store the index of the list. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update the list index directly, because it is derived by examining where an object is in the parent's child list.  If an object was at index 10 in the list, and the `list-index` property was set to 5, which should Hibernate use?

So typically you tell Hibernate what column to use to store the list index, and forget about it after that.

But if you are wanting to map the `list-index` property to your object in order to have direct access to it (in a readonly way, such as `getIndexInList()`), you have to map it with `insert=false update=false`.

I'm a little rusty with XML mapping, but here is something close to what I believe will work.  Let me know if you have issues and what error message you get.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.example.Node" table="node">
    <id name="id" column="nodeId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property
        name="listIndex"
        column="listIndex"
        insert="false"
        update="false" />

    <many-to-one
        name="parent"
        column="parentNodeId"
        class="com.example.Node"/>

    <list name="children" inverse="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="parentNodeId"/>
        <list-index column="listIndex"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.example.Node"/>
    </list>

 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks SeanA for your reply, unfortunately it still does not work. When I said that i can't update the list index, by that i did not mean that i wish to do it myself, but that hibernate does not update the listIndex. In the database the whole column for "listIndex" shows the default values !!!

Comment: SeanA, I think when invers="true" for list, then hibernate skips it and does not update the list-index column. I think this is a bug in Hibernate.

Comment: javaman, try adding cascade="all" to the <list> element.  Also, try adding a <key column="parentNodeId"/> inside the <list>.  See updated XML.  Seems like the "parentNodeId" might complain about being mapped twice, so if it does, try removing it from the many-to-one.  Let me know if that works!